# Firebase admin - get user details by uuid in server

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I am using node.js and want to retrieve the user details such as the email given that I have a specific token.

I know it can be manually through the console, I need a way to retrieve it automatically.

Alternatively - I can also make use of a way to just confirm that certain email matches a certain uuid.

Comment: Do you use Firebase Cloud Functions ?

Comment: Looking up a user by their UID is done by calling [`admin.auth().getUser(uid)` in the Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#retrieve_user_data). But I somehow get the feeling that is not what you are asking. I'm not really clear what you have right now. Can you share the minimal code that reproduces where you are stuck?

Comment: This is whay I neeed, thanks.